# attribute not specified and end tag not finished?

Tags: html, w3c, w3c-validation

I'm getting some weird errors when I [run my site through the W3C validation tool](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=merspi.com.au) for HTML 4.01 Transitional.

The errors are:

```
Line 9, Column 9: required attribute "TYPE" not specified
Line 34, Column 7: required attribute "TYPE" not specified
Line 1183, Column 10: end tag for "UL" which is not finished
```

I'm guessing the first is due to not specifying `type="text/css"` in the `<style>` tag on line 24 (I'm not sure why it says line 9 above) - is that correct?

But the other two have me stumped:

As far as I can tell, I've closed all my `</UL>` tags and applied `type="..."` everywhere else to `<script>` and `<style>`.

I've also had a look at those line numbers and can't see where the error is.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first two errors, you should have `<style type="text/css">` instead of just `<style>`:

```
<STYLE type="text/css"><!--
  .qa-body-js-on .qa-notice {display:none;}
//--></STYLE>
```

and

```
<style type="text/css">
  #qa-share-buttons-container {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #DDDDDD;
    font-size: 125%;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 20px 0;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  ..                
</style>
```

For the last error, as stated by the validation output:

> > Another possibility is that you used an element which requires a child element that you did not include. Hence the parent element is "not finished", not complete.

In this case, your `<ul>` node starting at line 1182 is just:

```
<UL CLASS="qa-nav-footer-list">
</UL>
```

You will need to add some children to the unordered list.

Comment: Thanks! It's now validating successfully: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=merspi.com.au

Answer (score 1):

Your `ul` has no list items within it:

```
<UL CLASS="qa-nav-footer-list">
</UL>
```

so should be:

```
<ul CLASS="qa-nav-footer-list">
    <li>Some list items</li>
    <li>Some list items</li>
</ul>
```

and both `style` tags are missing `type="text/css"` (lines 9 and 34)